# Why is the headless mode not working in Chrome?

Tags: selenium, go, selenium-chromedriver, headless-browser

in golang
"github.com/fedesog/webdriver"

I'm using a package, I need a headless mode, I've coded as below, but it doesn't work, I don't know why. Do you know what the problem is?

```
chromeDriver := webdriver.NewChromeDriver("./chromedriver")
err := chromeDriver.Start()
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
desired := webdriver.Capabilities{"Platform": "mac", "arguments": []string{"--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1200", "--ignore-certificate-errors", "--disable-extensions", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-dev-shm-usage"}}
required := webdriver.Capabilities{"arguments": []string{"--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1200", "--ignore-certificate-errors", "--disable-extensions", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-dev-shm-usage"}}
session, err := chromeDriver.NewSession(desired, required)
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
```

Comment: Do you see any error? Update the question.

Comment: No error just dont work headless mode i dont know why dont work by headless mode

Comment: I want work by headless mode